# Take data even just a table inner join sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, inner-join

```
SELECT * 
FROM RIC_RegistrazioneInformazioniCaricaBatteria t1 
INNER JOIN RCB_RegistrazioneCaricaBatteria t2 
ON t1.RIC_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS = t2.RCB_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS 
WHERE t2.RCB_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS = 394889
```

They are impractical SQL server, and I wonder if with an inner join can return the data even in a table.

In my case in RIC_RegistrazioneInformazioniCaricaBatteria table I have rows with the number 394889.
Instead RCB_RegistrazioneCaricaBatteria in Table I of the record with the code 394889.
And 'possible to return data even if they are in one table?

Or should I change the query?

Comment: It sounds like you may want a `FULL OUTER JOIN` so that if the `RCB_MCC_NUMERO_SERIE_MS` exists in either table the record will be returned.

Comment: @JNevill FULL OUTER JOIN works, do you answer the question? i set right it

Comment: As written, you'll only return 394889 if it exists in t2.  To get around that, you'll need to use the Full Outer Join as mentioned previously and change your WHERE clause to include:
OR t1.RIC_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS = 394889

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may want a `FULL OUTER JOIN` so that if the `RCB_MCC_NUMERO_SERIE_MS` exists in either table the record will be returned.

`INNER JOIN` will only return if it's in both tables

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` will return if it's in the leftmost table regardless if it's in the joined table. And `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` will do the opposite.